# Place a Pin MKMapView

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to place a pin whenever the screen is touched using MKMapView inside the method ViewDidLoad()

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        mapView.ShowsUserLocation = true;
        MKUserLocation currentLocation = mapView.UserLocation;
}
```

How would I go about doing this? The Xamarindocs are specific about placing an image, but how do I place a pin? Isn't it built into MKMapView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add an [MKAnnotation to the Map](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/map_view/add_an_annotation_to_a_map/)

```
class BasicMapAnnotation : MKAnnotation{
    public override CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate {get;set;}
    string title, subtitle;
    public override string Title { get{ return title; }}
    public override string Subtitle { get{ return subtitle; }}
    public BasicMapAnnotation (CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate, string title, string subtitle) {
        this.Coordinate = coordinate;
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }
}

var annotation = new BasicMapAnnotation (new CLLocationCoordinate2D(48.857,2.351), "Paris", "City of Light");
mapView.AddAnnotation(annotation);
```